# Can it be said that 4^n=Big-0(3^n)?

Tags: algorithm

Can we say that the Big-0(3^n)=Big-0(4^n)?

When you use L'Hospital's Rule to differentiate 4^n/3^n, you get the same exponent factored out of the numerators and denominators? So that means at the end you must get (4.n!)/(3.n!).
Going by the rules of Big O-notation, if the remnant limit (n-->\infty) f(x)/g(x) is a constant then f(x) and g(x) are of the same parity, which means Big-theta(4^n)=Big-theta(3^n).
Am I right?
Please make your argument.

Comment: No, because 4^n is larger than 3^n by a factor of (4/3)^n. For large n, this tends toward infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that `3^n = O(4^n)` but `4^n ≠ O(3^n)` because `(4/3)^n` is unbounded.